# PDF Grabbing Code is terminated (Cache full trying to find a workaround)

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

So I just started coding with Python. I have a lot of pdfs which are my target for data grabbing. I have the script finished and it works with out errors if I limit it to a small number of pdfs (~200). If i let the skript run with 4000 pdfs the script is terminated without an error. Friend of mine told me that this is due to the cache.

I save the grabbed data to a list and in the last step create a DataFrame out of the different lists. The DataFrame is then exported to excel.

So i tried to export the DataFrame after 200 pdfs (and then clear all lists and the dataframe) but then pandas overwrites the prior results. Is this the right way to go? Or can anyone think of a different approach to get arround the Termination by large number of pdfs?

Right now i use:

```
   MN=list()
   Vds=list()
   data={'Materialnummer': MN,'Verwendung des Stoffs':VdS}
   df=pd.DataFrame(data)
   df.to_excel('test.xls')
```

Comment: Your question is about Pandas DataFrame but you mention PDF in your title and tags. Please make sure title and tags agree with the actual question.

Comment: Please show a little more of your code. How are you reading these PDFs, what are you doing with them, what do you need to do in the end? (Also, I wonder what cache your friend is talking about...)